# What is the best method to obtain dollar value with cents from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm hoping to obtain the most elegant solution (least amount of typed code) for the requirement of converting a penny string into a dollar cent value. It must represent the cents (.00), so dividing by 100 is not straight forward. For example "00000600000" has to be represented as "6000.00". I've produced the following methods:

```
value = Math.Abs(Int(Mid(Mid(line, 188, 11), 1, Len(Mid(line, 188, 11)) - 2))) & "." & Mid(Mid(line, 188, 11), Len(Mid(line, 188, 11)) - 1, 2) 

value = (Math.Abs(Int(Mid(line, 188, 11))).ToString).Insert(Math.Abs(Int(Mid(line, 188, 11))).ToString.Length - 2, ".")

value = Math.Abs(Int(Mid(line, 188, 11))) : value = value.Insert(value.Length - 2, ".")
```

Comment: _"most elegant solution"_ is subjective

Comment: "dividing by 100 is not straight forward" why not?

Comment: The value will not show the cents as .00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int cents = int.Parse(line);
decimal dollars = cents / 100m;
string value = dollars.ToString("$#.00");
```

Or, if your definition of *elegant* implies "fewer lines":

```
value = (int.Parse(line) / 100m).ToString("$#.00");
```

Comment: _technically_ you could do `decimal.Parse` too which would support more digits.

Comment: After scanning the documentation for this function I used something like ("#.##") gathering that it may be matched based. After you answered with ("$#.00") I wondered if I would have to otherwise omit the dollar sign, but simply using ("#.00") works!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Dim str as string = "0006500000"
Dim d as decimal = cdec(str) / 100
Msgbox(d.tostring("#.##"))
```